# How to import my own class into Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

I create simple class (mymodule.ts):

```
export module MyModule {

export class MyClass  {
    Name: string;
    greet() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }       
  }
}
```

So, i have server.ts class (nodejs):

```
import http = require('http');
import my = require("mymodule");
var test=new my.MyModule.MyClass();
test.greet();
port = process.env.port || 1337
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);
```

But, i have error: `Error TS2307 Cannot find module 'mymodule'.`

I am new into node and typescript (C# background), so can you help me: how to include my own class into another class at nodejs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the export module part and leave just:

```
export class MyClass  {
    Name: string;
    greet() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }       
  }
```

File is already a module in typescript.

And then:

```
var test=new my.MyClass();
```

Hope this helps.